# Forwarding difference between local and server using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, forward

I forwarded like that:

```
request.setAttribute("message", "My message is written here.");
...
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Folder1/Folder2/message.jsp")
                                              .forward(request, response);
```

And in jsp I get the data using this code:

```
<h3>${message}</h3>
```

This codes works in my localhost but in server the result is "${message}". How to solve it?

Comment: You are setting the `request` attribute after forwarding the `request` to some other JSP . Try putting the last line in your code before the line where you forward .

Comment: This code works successfully in localhost. If it true which you said then this code wouldn't work in localhost or server

Comment: I am not sure how it works !!! It shouldn't probably .

Comment: any stacktrace of missing libs?